# Android managing task about single task and task affinity

Tags: android, android-activity

After looking into the codes i need to maintain/modify and the different documents and explanation, i really got confused single task and task affinity.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html
https://www.slideshare.net/RanNachmany/manipulating-android-tasks-and-back-stack
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

What i understand is activity launch mode singleTask will create a new task and put that activity at the root of the task. "singleTask" and "singleInstance", should be used only when the activity has an ACTION_MAIN and a CATEGORY_LAUNCHER filter

activity taskAffinity is the task that the activity has an affinity for. By default all the activities share the same affinity, the default package name. If want to have the activity different affinity task, then define another name and launch with FLAG_NEW_ACTIVITY_TASK.

In my maintain code(not the original developer), there have so many activities in AndroidManifest.xml with launchMode singleTask.

```
<activity name="LauncherActivity"
          launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter> 
         <action name="action.MAIN" />
         <category name="category.LAUNCHER />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity name="TabsActivity"
          launchMode="singleTask">  
</activity>

<activity name="SubTab1"
          launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>

<activity name="SubTab2"
          launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>

<activity name="SubTab3"
          launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>

<activity name="SubTab4"
          launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>

<activity name="ScreenActivity"
          launchMode="singleTask"
          taskAffinity="com.xxx.xxx.sa"
          excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```

- When click on user icon,

  1. it will launch the LauncherActivity. LauncherActivity do some tasks for checking and launch TabsActivity and finish
     itself(LauncherActivity).
  2. TabsActivity add Tabs (SubTab1, SubTab2, SubTab3, SubTab4).
  3. ScreenActivity will be launched startActivity with
     FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
  4. ScreenActivity also put a notification icon so that the user can directly back to this activity.

SubTab can launch the other standard launchMode which will be destroyed after use back key.

EveryTime user click on App icon, it will take to TabsActivity instead of the last activity the user interact. So I add some code in the LauncherActivity onCreate()

```
if (!isTaskRoot() && !TextUtils.isEmpty(action)) {
            if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) &&
                    Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(action)) {
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
```

This successfully bring to the last activity that the user interact.

The first question comes to me that isTaskRoot(). According to the explanation:
boolean isTaskRoot ()
Return whether this activity is the root of a task. The root is the first activity in a task.

LauncherActivity defined as singleTask as mentioned above, so it should be the root in the task. But when onCreate() check that, it is not the root task when there is other activity is launched including SingleTask activity. When TabsActivity is launched, when click on AppIcon, LauncherActivity onCreate() isTaskRoot() return false. 
LauncherActivity and TabsActivity, they should be in different tasks and in each task, each would be the root activity. 
In some other comments, it mentioned that isTaskRoot() is true when there are no activities in activity stack. So if there is activity in the stack, if will return false. So it is more related to the stack instead of task? I really get confused. Can someone explain about why it is different with document explanation.

The second modification is that I removed the ScreenActivity taskAffinity. In the old design, ScreenActivity can be be backed to through clicking on notification. But there is new request that if there is ScreenActivity last launched by user, when click on App icon, it should back to that activity. After removed taskAffinity in AndroidManifest, it does happen what i want. 
I am looking this slide share tutorial. But still not get that. 
https://www.slideshare.net/rajdeep/managing-activity-backstack

My question is that if the singleTask without taskAffinity, how they create a new task for each different singleTask activity. How the backstack works?

After modification, LauncherActivity, TabsActivity, ScreenActivity are SingleTask with the same default package name task. So they are in the same task stacked? If yes, it is not the same with document explanation. Please help me to get more clear of that.

Thanks a lot.